# What is the purpose of using Rails' asset pipeline in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I understand its purpose in development, but when I precompile my assets upon deploy, it seems like it would make the most sense simplify and turn it off in production. Is it only for fingerprinting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be silly to recompile assets every request. That is why `config/environments/production.rb` contains `config.assets.compile = false`, which forces you to precompile your assets. If they're precompiled, the assets are served statically - as the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) explains.

However, `config.assets.enabled = false` completely disables the asset pipeline so that you can't even precompile your assets - it assumes that you are doing the old-school method of hand-generating assets and putting them in the `public` folder yourself.

Comment: Ok, I guess I was wondering what the reasoning behind the default of `true` in `production.rb` was. I suppose it's to cover those who don't precompile assets.

Comment: No, by default (at least on Rails 3.2), production.rb has `config.assets.compile = false` so you *have* to precompile assets.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `config.assets.enabled = true`.

Comment: Ah ok, well if you set that to `false` you won't even be able to precompile your assets. I've updated my answer to make the difference between `assets.compile` and `assets.enable` clear.

Answer (score 1):

It minimizes the code size and compiles separate files into one to improve download speeds.

The assets are precompiled, whether it's locally or in production.
The finger-printing will make sure that when you push changes out to production, people don't stay with older copies in their browsers cache.

Comment: Right. I understand the purpose of the Asset Pipeline. I'm wondering why one would leave it enabled in production, when you can just precompile upon deploy.